# What am I doing wrong with this redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like:

```
http://www.example.com/tag/abc
```

to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/blog/tag/abc
```

I've got:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^tag/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/tag/$1
```

as my redirect rule and it ends up 404ing instead of redirecting.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the URL change in address bar? Try changing `^tag` to `^/tag`

Comment: Nope, the URL does not change. Will try.

Comment: That did it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're used to mod_rewrite in .htaccess where you do not match against the entire URL. But for Redirect/RedirectMatch, you are implicitly matching against the entire path component of the URL.

In other words, /tag/abc which does not match your regex of ^tag.